# Google checkout callback can't seem to reach https server

Tags: google-checkout

I am trying to implement Google Check out (GCO) on a new server, the process seemed to work fine on the old server.

The error from GCO integration console is the timeout error you might expect if there is load on the server and/or the response takes longer than 3 seconds to respond.

To perform a test (not integrating with my database), I have set some code to send an email to me instead. If I hit the https url manually, I get the email and I can see an output to the screen. If I then leave it as that, Google still returns the Timeout error and I don't get an email. So I have doubts as to whether google is even able to hit the https url.

I did temporarily attempt to use the unsecure url for testing and indeed I received the email, however this solution isn't the route we've developed for, so the problem is something to do with the secure url specifically.

I have looked into the certificate which is a UTN-USERFirst-Hardware which is listed as accepted on http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=57856 . I have also tried to temporarily disable the firewall with no joy. Does anyone have any sugestions?

Comment: ok, I've managed to get access to find out what the server logs say. It seems that when GCO attempt to hit our server they get a 401 (authorisation failed) error thus the 3 second rule is exceeded and explains the timeout error message. If we hit the urls directly via a browser, we get the correct responsecode 200. I'm not sure at this stage why this would be as the directory the callback file resides in isn't password protected.

Suggestions on a postcard.

Comment: This issue is resolved.
Google send through a username/password combination (made up of your google merchant idfor username and google merchant key for password)
You need to create a user for this user on the server and set the directory to "basic authentication". Once this is done the 401 error goes away as the server knows about the user that is attempting to send the XML to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to hear you figured out the problem.

I'm adding the links below to add a litle more context for future readers about how Google Checkout uses HTTP Basic Authentication:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#urls_for_posting

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#https_auth_scheme

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_API.html#Receiving_and_Processing_Notifications